# Fragment with activated onclick event belonging to another fragment

Tags: android, onclick, fragment

I detected something strange when executing my code.

I deleted a lot of code to try to detect the error.

I use two fragment.

In the first Fragment I read from a database using volley +.
When loading a new fragment, by clicking on the fragment, the onclik event of the previous fragment continues to work on the new fragment.

The code executes correctly in the RecyclerView, reads the data from the remote database and no error is detected.

The code of the second fragment: CommentariosArticulo I have not put it because it is empty, only the default template generated by android Studio

I have also verified that if I delete all the code
inside the fragment: ListadoArticulos.java
referring to volley and referring to the Recyclerview and call the second fragment the problem disappears

```
Articulo.java
---------------

public class Articulo {
    private Integer id;
    private String titulo;
    private String contenido;
    private String fecha;

    public Integer getId() {      return id;    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {   this.id = id;    }

    public String getTitulo() {  return titulo;    }

    public void setTitulo(String titulo) {  this.titulo = titulo;    }

    public String getContenido() {  return contenido;    }

    public void setContenido(String contenido) {  this.contenido = contenido;    }

    public String getFecha() {  return fecha;    }

    public void setFecha(String fecha) {  this.fecha = fecha; }
}



ArticulosAdapter.java
---------------------

package com.example.suso.audioblogsuso_pru003.datos;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.suso.audioblogsuso_pru003.R;

import java.util.List;

public class ArticulosAdapter extends
        RecyclerView.Adapter<ArticulosAdapter.ArticulosHolder>
        implements View.OnClickListener{

    private List<Articulo> listaArticulos;
    private View.OnClickListener onClickListener;

    public ArticulosAdapter(List<Articulo> listaArticulos) {
        this.listaArticulos = listaArticulos;
    }

    @Override
    public ArticulosHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View vista= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.articulos_item,parent,false);

        RecyclerView.LayoutParams layoutParams=new RecyclerView.
                LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        vista.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        vista.setOnClickListener(this); // para que capte el evento click
        return new ArticulosHolder(vista);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ArticulosHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.txtId.setText(listaArticulos.get(position).getId().toString());
        holder.txtTitulo.setText(listaArticulos.get(position).getTitulo().toString());
        holder.txtFecha.setText(listaArticulos.get(position).getFecha().toString());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listaArticulos.size();
    }

    public void setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener onClickListener){
        this.onClickListener = onClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(onClickListener != null){
            onClickListener.onClick(v);
        }
    }

    public class ArticulosHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView txtId, txtTitulo, txtFecha;

        public ArticulosHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            txtId = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idArticulo);
            txtTitulo = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tituloArticulo);
            txtFecha =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fechaArticulo);
        }
    }
}


mainActivity.java
-----------------

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener ,

        ComentariosArticulo.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        ListadoArticulos.OnFragmentInteractionListener

{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        Fragment miFragment = null;
        boolean fragmentSeleccionado = false;

        if  (id == R.id.listadoArticulos) {
            miFragment = new ListadoArticulos();
            fragmentSeleccionado=true;
        }

        if(fragmentSeleccionado){
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main,miFragment).commit();
        }


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }




Listado Articulos.java
----------------------


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link ListadoArticulos.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link ListadoArticulos#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class ListadoArticulos extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;


    MiAplicacion miAplicacion;

    RecyclerView recyclerArticulos;
    ArrayList<Articulo> listaArticulos;

    RequestQueue request;
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest;

    TextView tvLoadingListadoArticulos;


    public ListadoArticulos() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment ListadoArticulos.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static ListadoArticulos newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        ListadoArticulos fragment = new ListadoArticulos();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listado_articulos, container, false);

        miAplicacion = (MiAplicacion) getContext().getApplicationContext();

        tvLoadingListadoArticulos = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvLoadingListadoArticulos);


        listaArticulos=new ArrayList<>();

        recyclerArticulos= (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.IdReciclerViewListadoArticulos);

        //El LayoutManager se encarga del layout de todas las vistas dentro del RecyclerView
        recyclerArticulos.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getContext()));

        //el tamaño del recyclerView no depende del adaptador
        recyclerArticulos.setHasFixedSize(true);

        request = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        request.getCache().clear();

        cargarWebServiceWeb();


        return view;
    }




    private void cargarWebServiceWeb() {

        String scriptPhp ="listado-articulos.php";
        String url= miAplicacion.getUrlHostScriptPhp()+scriptPhp;


        jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                url,
                null,
                createMyReqSuccessListenerArticulos(),
                createMyReqErrorListenerArticulos());

        request.add(jsonObjectRequest);

    }

    private Response.Listener<JSONObject> createMyReqSuccessListenerArticulos() {
        return new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                if(response.isNull("articulos")){
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No se encontró ningun articulo " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    tvLoadingListadoArticulos.setHeight(0);
                    return;
                }

                Articulo articulo=null;
                JSONArray json=response.optJSONArray("articulos");
                try {

                    for (int i=0;i<json.length();i++){
                        articulo=new Articulo();
                        JSONObject jsonObject=null;
                        jsonObject=json.getJSONObject(i);

                        articulo.setId((Integer)jsonObject.optInt("ID"));
                        articulo.setTitulo(jsonObject.optString("post_title"));
                        articulo.setContenido(jsonObject.optString("post_content"));
                        articulo.setFecha("fecha");

                        listaArticulos.add(articulo);
                    }
                    ArticulosAdapter adapter=new ArticulosAdapter(listaArticulos);
                    adapter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"estoy creando un nuevo fragment", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            // Crea el nuevo fragmento y la transacción.
                            Fragment miFragment = new ComentariosArticulo();
                            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                            //el id:R.id.BuscarArticulosCategoria pertenece al
                            //contenedor del fragment_buscar_articulos_categoria.xml (fragment actual)
                            transaction.replace(R.id.contenListadoArticulos, miFragment);
                            transaction.addToBackStack(null);

                            // Commit a la transacción
                            transaction.commit();



                        }
                    });

                    tvLoadingListadoArticulos.setHeight(0);
                    recyclerArticulos.setAdapter(adapter);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No se ha podido establecer conexión con el servidor" +
                            " "+response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        };
    }


    private Response.ErrorListener createMyReqErrorListenerArticulos() {
        return new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No se ha podido conectar con el servidor" + error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.i("ERROR", error.toString());
            }
        };
    }



    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}


Articulos_item.xml
------------------

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/idArticulo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="18"
            android:text="id"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tituloArticulo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="6"
            android:text="titulo"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fechaArticulo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="13"
            android:text="fecha"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#979B9C"/>

</LinearLayout>



fragment_listado_articulos.xml
------------------------------

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/contenListadoArticulos"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFE2E7EA"
    tools:context=".gestion_datos.ListadoArticulos">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/border_style2"
                android:paddingBottom="6dp"
                android:paddingTop="6dp"
                android:text="Listado Artículos"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/IdReciclerViewListadoArticulos"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:textAlignment="center">

                    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvLoadingListadoArticulos"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorNaranjaCrema2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="cargando ...."
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:text="Selecciona un Un Artículo"
                android:textSize="16dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</FrameLayout>



fragment_comentarios_articulo.xml
----------------------------------

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/contenComentariosArticulo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/coloNaranjaCremar"
    tools:context=".gestion_datos.ComentariosArticulo">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


    </LinearLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are adding the CommentariosArticulo Fragment as a child to the ListadoArticulos Fragment, and both the CommentariosArticulo fragment and the recyclerview reside in the same FrameLayout contenListadoArticulos.

You need to replace the fragment in the MainActivity class not in ListadoArticulos.

Just move the following code from your ListadoArticulos to MainActivity

```
Fragment miFragment = new ComentariosArticulo();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

//el id:R.id.BuscarArticulosCategoria pertenece al
//contenedor del fragment_buscar_articulos_categoria.xml (fragment actual)
transaction.replace(R.id.contenListadoArticulos, miFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit a la transacción
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: I understand, thank you very much, but I am interested in being able to create the fragment just after having created the first fragment, that is to say; in the first fragment I read the articles, and I select an article and when clicking click I create another fragment with the selected article, if I used replace, should I replace the first fragrament?

Comment: Yes, you should replace the first fragment with the new fragment.

Comment: I've read that you can replace a fragment from another fragment, is not that how I did it then?

Comment: So there is a fragment stack in an activity and a child fragment stack in the fragment itself. You have added Fragment A in the activity's stack but you are adding the Fragment B to Fragment A's child fragment stack. What you should be doing is replacing Fragment A with Fragment B in the activity's fragment stack.

Comment: thank you very much I understood and I will try it, for now what I have done as a solution is to use only activitys